# Subreport parameter not showing as a selectable parameter for linking in crystal reports 2008

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, asp.net-2.0

I have a crystal report designed in vs 2008 crystal reports. There is the main report and 3 sub reports. Each of these sub reports and the main one have information generated by a report number the fields are not named the same but in two of the three sub reports i have been able to link the parameter to the main report parameter that i am passing in the code behind. However when I go to link the third subreport the parameter used is not showing up in the dropdown used to select the parameter to link. Anyone have any ideas why this might be happening.

I have a horrible tendency to speak in shorthand so if you need more info let me know and I will do my best to answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are the two fields are same data types?

Comment: They actually were not. If you phrase as an answer i will accept it. in the stored proc I was passing an int and the orignal variable i was linking to was a string. Thanks for posting helped me get to the right place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that the fields that you intend to link are the same data type.

Incidentally, this is how Crystal Reports 'supports' heterogeneous joins.  You can link a string to a numeric value, as long as you convert one of the fields to match the data type of the other (via a formula field).

I've also gotten around the heterogeneous-join issue by converting one of the fields using a SQL-expression field.  Then you perform the 'linking' in the record-selection formula.

Comment: Thank you!  I had DATE on one, DATETIME on the other, and your answer is still helping.